# io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError SEVERE: (where the default port is 4444)

Tags: eclipse, selenium, maven

I want to run basic selenium code in eclipse but get the following error.how can I fix it
*io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError
SEVERE: (where the default port is 4444)*
the code is following

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LaunchApplication {
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\selenium-java-4.4.0\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

The full error

```
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError
SEVERE: The valid arguments for WebDriverManager CLI are:
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError
SEVERE: 1. For resolving drivers locally:
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError
SEVERE:     resolveDriverFor browserName <browserVersion>
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError
SEVERE: (where browserName is: chrome|edge|firefox|opera|chromium|iexplorer)
Sep 20, 2022 2:43:11 PM io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError
SEVERE: 
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError
SEVERE: 2. For running a browser in a Docker (and use it trough noVNC):
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError
SEVERE:     runInDocker browserName <browserVersion>
Sep 20, 2022 2:43:11 PM io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError
SEVERE: (where browserName is: chrome|edge|firefox|opera|safari|chrome-mobile)
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError
SEVERE: 
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError
SEVERE: 3. For starting WebDriverManager Server:
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError
SEVERE:     server <port>
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager logCliError
SEVERE: (where the default port is 4444)
```

Comment: Add the full error `trace`

Comment: added it to question